# Oracle Data Integrator- ODI 12.2.1--Loadplan Issue no of records count issue

Tags: oracle, etl, oracle-data-integrator

I come across a scenario in my project.I am loading data from file to Table using ODI.I am running My interfaces through loadplan.I've 1000 Records in my source file,and also getting 1000 records in target file.but when I'm checking ODI  loadplan execution log its showing number of insert is 2000.can anyone please help.or is it a ODI bug.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of inserts does not only show the inserts in the target table but also all the insert happening in temporary tables. Depending on the knowledge modules (KMs) used in an interface, ODI might load data in a C$_ table (LKM) or I$_ table (IKM/CKM). The rows loaded in these table will also be counted.

You can look at the code generated in the operator to check if your KMs are using using these temporary. You can also simulate an execution to see the code generated.